# Kmeans cluster size change quite a bit on each run

Tags: clustering, k-means

I am running a kmeans on a sample size of 1000 data. The data is scaled (z).

When I run kmeans(df, nstart=25, centers=5)- it runs and I can get the size of each cluster. The largest group has 620 in it.

I ran it again (I did not mean to), but noticed the largest cluster then had 450 in it.

Out of interest, I kept trying and got the largest cluster to be anywhere between 450-800.

Now I know that the initialization can effect the clusters and cluster sizes. HOWEVER, I am surprised it varies so much. If my cluster sizes changed by 10-20, then I would get it. But these are large swings.

Of course I can set.seed to stop it- but it seems too odd to get that wide variation of results.

It seems too random that I might get the largest cluster of 450 or 600 or 775 based on when I ran it (or where it initialized). I feel uncomfortable with the results now.

Thoughts or explanations.

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that k-means might not be a good clustering algorithm for *your data*.

Most likely, you don't have well-separated clusters of similar size and weight; which is when k-means works well. K-means makes some pretty strong assumptions on the data, and when these do not hold, the result can become as bad as any other random convex partitioning.

For example, k-means is known to suffer from outliers. Outliers can cause clusters to generate to a few outliers only, which effectively reduces your k. If this happens, the results of k=i and k=i+1 can become near identical.

In fact I recommend that people run k-means several times, and when they observe a high variance in the results, k-means was a bad choice. Also, **visualize your results**. Choose some 2 dimensional projection (e.g. on your primary components, or even a series of scatter plots) and try to **visually inspect your result for usefulness**. If it *looks* useless to you, it probably *is*.

Can you update your question with such projections of your data, in particular for two very different results?

Answer (score 0):

Thats strongly depends on your data. Example:

```
> a=rbind(matrix(rnorm(6000),600,10),matrix(rnorm(4000)/2+c(rep(2,400),rep(0,3600)),400,10))

> kmeans(a,5,nstart=25)$size
[1] 129 458 137 133 143

> kmeans(a,5,nstart=25)$size
[1] 469 134 126 128 143

> kmeans(a,5,nstart=25)$size
[1] 138 463 134 139 126

> kmeans(a,5,nstart=25)$size
[1] 140 127 467 125 141
```

Comment: interesting. So your example was rather stable. What about my data (in general) could make it so unstable??? Distribution? Something else? I also scaled it. Thanks for this and your comments.

Comment: Try to do dimensionality reduction to 2d/3d and draw your clusters.